# How do I define my own range function in Python

Tags: python, function, range

Below I've attached a homework problem. So far my only code is.

```
def myRange(start, stop=None, step=None):

    if stop == None:
        stop = start

    if step == None:
        step = 1

    while True:
        if step > 0 and start >= stop:
            break
        elif step < 0 and start <= stop:
            break
        yield ('%g' % start)
        start = start + step
        break

    lyst = myRange(start, stop=None, step=None)
    for num in lyst:
        print(num)

myRange(0, 10, 2)
```

I'm trying to get rid of the yeild and the '%g' statement and replace it with a return statement if anyone has any idea about how to do that. As well as that I am trying to make it so this truly works like a function and you can pass variables into it and get the range as a list, but I'm not sure how to do that either. Any help would be appreciated. I am very lost on this one.

> Define and test a function myRange. This function should behave like
>   Python’s standard range function, with the required and optional
>   arguments, but it should return a list. Do not use the range function
>   in your implementation! (Hints: Study Python’s help on range to
>   determine the names, positions, and what to do with your function’s
>   parameters. Use a default value of None for the two optional
>   parameters. If these parameters both equal None, then the function has
>   been called with just the stop value. If just the third parameter
>   equals None, then the function has been called with a start value as
>   well. Thus, the first part of the function’s code establishes what the
>   values of the parameters are or should be. The rest of the code uses
>   those values to build a list by counting up or down.)

Comment: What have you tried so far and what isn't working?

Comment: I have hardly tried anything. I just am lost on how to do this.

Comment: well I'd start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) with the range function docs from there you at least know you need to create a function like this `def myRange(start=None, stop, step=None):`

Comment: Ah, I did get that far but I'm mostly confused about the list part of this.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). You say you "got that far", but in your post you say you don't know where to start, so you've apparently thought of something... Please edit your post to include even your thoughts if you have no code.

Comment: I did not figure that would be important as it's barely scratching the surface of this problem, but I see now that I should have stated that. Still, if anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your post with anything you've attempted or researched so far.

Comment: Just edited it.

Comment: Alright, so "should return a list"... Do you know how to define a list, add values to it, then return it? Doesn't matter if the values are currently correct. Just return any list for now.

Comment: `return` will return whatever you want it to from a function. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) will answer a lot of questions for you i would start with `append`

Comment: I am familiar how to define a list and add values to it etc. I'm more so confused on what it means to return a list. Say you set the required stop parameter to 10, is it supposed to make an incrementing list from 0 - 9?

Comment: Yes, if step and start are not provided, then you would return `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`... You can play with `print(list(range(10))` to see what your code *should return* with `print(myRange(10))`

Comment: I've come up with something to help visualize even though I can't use the range function. Check my post to see it, and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

```
    myRange(start=None, stop=10, step=None):
```

1. ### Dealing with `stop=10`

   You set a default value of `stop = 10`. However, you created were asked to mimic the built-in
   range function. The built in range does not have default `stop=10`.
   So, do not set a default value in your version if 
   there is no default value in the original
2. ### Minimum number of args needed

   Your `myRange` has 3 default arguments. Have you have ever seen the following code?

   ```
   for x in range():
       print(x)
   ```

   Hint: `range` requires at least one argument.
3. ### Default value for start

   `10` is the stop. What is the first number printed by the following code? Is it `0`? Is it `1`? `2`? `5`? `10`? What is it?

   ```
   for x in range(10):
       print(x)
   ```
4. ### Put the `print` outside of `myRange`

   The indented block of code should not contain any print statements

   ```
   def myRange(start=None, stop=10, step=None):
       lyst = (list(range(stop)))
       # print (lyst) Noooo!

   lyst = myRange()
   print(lyst) # YES!
   ```
5. ### You need a `return` statement

If a function has output we write `return output` You're supposed to return a `list`

> This function should behave like Python’s standard range function, with the required and optional arguments, ***but it should return a list***.

```
    def myRange(start=None, stop=10, step=None):
        lyst = list(range(stop))
        # print (lyst) Noooo!
        return lyst # New feature! return the output:)

    lyst = myRange()
    print(lyst) # YES!
```

## Edit

I have decided to give you a function signature. You will still have to fill in the body. Don't worry about most of the code, leave it alone. Simply write your code at the very end, replacing the `print("start:", start, "stop:", stop, "step:", step)`

```
is_none = lambda x:\
    x == None

count_non_none = lambda args, *, is_none=is_none: {\
    sum(1 for _ in filter(is_none, args))
}   

def myRange(_a1, _a2=None, _a3=None, *, start=None, stop=None, step=None):
    args_non_none   = count_non_none((_a1, _a2, _a3))
    kwargs_non_none = count_non_none((start, stop, step))
    total_non_none  = args_non_none + kwargs_non_none

    if total_non_none == 1:
        # the one arg represents `stop`
        assert(not start)
        assert(not step)
        stop = stop if stop else _a1            
    elif total_non_none == 2:
        if args_non_none == 2:
            start = _a1
            stop  = _a2
         else # at least one keyword argument
             assert(not (start and step))
             L = [_a1, _a2, _a3]
             while len(L) > 0:
                 if not start:
                     start = L.pop(0)
                 elif not stop:
                     stop = L.pop(0)
                 elif not step:
                     step = L.pop(0)
    elif total_non_none == 3:
        L = [_a1, _a2, _a3]
             while len(L) > 0:
                 if not start:
                     start = L.pop(0)
                 elif not stop:
                     stop = L.pop(0)
                 elif not step:
                     step = L.pop(0)                
    else:
        raise TypeError("more than 3 arguments were passed in")

    if start == None: 
        start = 0 
    if step == None: 
        step = 1 

    print("start:", start, "stop:", stop, "step:", step)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python allows you to accept any number of arguments and keyword arguments like this:

```
def myRange(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something
```

args will be a tuple, and kwargs will be a dictionary.
For example, calling myRange(21, 'foo', name='shado') will have args be (21, 'foo') and kwargs be {'name': 'shado'}.
args and kwargs don't technically have to be args and kwargs but it is convention to name them that.
using this I imagine you can construct some conditionals based on the length of args

```
def myRange(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        start, end, step = 0, args[0], 1
     # conditionals for other cases
```

another way to do it would be like this:

```
def myRange(start, stop=None, step=None):
    if stop == None and step == None:
        start, stop, step = 0, start, 1
    # handle the other conditions
```

basically just handling every case separately

For making the list I would use a while loop.

Comment: variadic functions having `*args, **kwargs` are not helpful in this case. There are only 3 arguments to content with. Keep it simple.

Comment: I thought it might make sense because passing in 10 to range (range(10)) makes stop = 10 but in the function the variable start would actually hold stop. And it’s an opportunity to learn something new. But I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

Defined range w/o using a range function.

```
def myRange(*args):
    myList=[]
    if len(args) is 1:
        k=0
        if args[0] > 0:
            while k < args[0]:
                myList.append(k)
                k=k+1
        else:
            while k > args[0]:
                myList.append(k)
                k=k-1
    elif len(args) is 2:
        k = args[0]
        if args[0] < args[1]:
            while k < args[1]:
                myList.append(k)
                k=k+1
        else:
            while k > args[1]:
                myList.append(k)
                k=k-1
    else:
        k=args[0]
        if args[0] < args[1]:
            while k < args[1]:
                myList.append(k)
                k=k+args[2]
        else:
            while k > args[1]:
                myList.append(k)
                k=k+args[2]
    return myList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myRange(start, step=None, stop=None):
    if step == None and stop == None:
        start, step, stop = 0, 1, start
        while start < stop:
            yield start
            start += step
    elif stop == None:
        start, step, stop = start, 1, step
        while start < stop:
            yield start
            start += step
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step


for i in myRange(1, 10, 100):
    print(i)
```

or you can also implement with args too.

```
def custome_range(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        start, step, stop = 0, 1, args[0]
        while start < stop:
            yield start
            start += step
    elif len(args) == 2:
        start, step, stop = args[0], 1, args[1]
        while start < stop:
            yield start
            start += step
    elif len(args) == 3:
        start, step, stop = args[0], args[1], args[2]
        while start < stop:
            yield start
            start += step


for i in custome_range(1, 10, 100):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this exclusively through if statements to determine which arguments are given when the function was called, followed by while statements to deliver the numbers in the range_list according to each parameter.

```
def myRange(a, b = None, step = None):

     range_list = []

     if b == None:
          b = 0

     if step == None:
         while a > b:
             range_list.append(b)
             b += 1
         while a < b:
             range_list.append(a)
             a += 1

     elif step > 0:
         while a < b:
             range_list.append(a)
             a += step

     elif step < 0:
         while a > b:
             range_list.append(a)
             a += step

     else:
         range_list = [a]

     return range_list
```